# What's the recommended way to handle microservice processing bugs new insights?

Tags: asynchronous, message-queue, microservices

Before I get to my question, let me sketch out a sample set of microservices to illustrate my dilemma.

### Scenario outline

Suppose I have 4 microservices:

An **activation service** where features supplied to our customers are (de)activated. A **registration service** where members can be added and changed. A **secured key service** that is able to generate secure keys (in a multi step process) for members to be used when communicating with them with the outside world. And a **communication service** that is used to communicate about our members with external vendors.

The **secured key service** may however only request secured keys if this is a feature that is activated. Additionally, the **communication service** may only communicate about members that have a secured key AND if the communication feature itself is activated.

Because they are microservices, each of the services has it's own datastore and is completely self sufficient. That is, any data that is required from the other microservices is duplicated locally and kept in sync by means of asynchronous messages from the other microservices.

### The dilemma

I'm actually facing two main dilemma's. The first is (pretty obviously) data synchronization. When there are multiple data stores that need to be kept in sync you have to account for messages getting lost or processed out of order. But there are plenty of out of the box solutions for this and when all fails you could even fall back to some kind of ETL process to keep things in sync.

The main issue I'm facing however is the actions that need to be performed. In the above example the **secured key service** must perform an action when it either

1. Receives a message from the **registration service** for a new member when it already knows that the *secured keys* feature is active in the **activation service**
2. Receives a message from the **activation service** that the *secured keys* feature is now active when it already knows about members from the **registration service**

In both cases this means that a message from the external system must lead to both an update in the local copy of the data as well as some logic that needs to be processed.

### The question

Now to the actual question :)

What is the recommended way to cope with either bugs or new insights when it comes to handling those messages? Suppose there is a bug in the message handler from the **activation service**. The handler does update the internal data structure, but it fails to detect that there are already registered members and thus never starts the *secure key generation* process. Alternatively it could be that there's no bug, but we decide that there is something else we want the handler to do.

The system will have no reason to resubmit or reprocess messages (as the message didn't fail), but there's no real way for us to re-trigger the behavior that's behind the message.

I hope it's clear what I'm asking (and I do apologize if it should be posted on any of the other 170 Stack... sites, I only really know of StackOverflow)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the *recommended* way, I know how this is done in [DDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) and maybe this can help you as DDD and `microservices` are friends.

What you have is a long-running/multi-step process that involves information from multiple microservices. In DDD this can be implemented using a [Saga/Process manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591569.aspx). The Saga maintains a local state by subscribing to events from both the `registration service` and the `activation service`. As the events come, the Saga check to see if it has all the information it needs to generate secure keys by submitting a `CreateSecureKey` command. The events may come in any order and even can be duplicated but this is not a problem as the Saga can compensate for this.

In case of bugs or new features, you could create special scripts or other processes that search for a particular situation and handle it by submitting specific compensating commands, without reprocessing all the past events.

In case of new features you may even have to process old events that now are interesting for your business process. You do this in the same way, by querying the events source for the newly interesting old events and send them to the newly updated Saga. After that *import process*, you subscribe the Saga to these newly interesting events and the Saga continues to function as usual.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I guess I'm just worried about potential theoretical issues. Looking at figure 2 in the article you reference, say that there is an issue with the Order Process Manager that causes is to sometimes not send a *make payment* request (step 7). Is there some standard or recommended approach to ensure that we can recover from such situations?

Comment: @Robba I don't think so, every failure has its own mode of recovery but this is OK if you think about the (most important) types of failure you want to detect an create (automated) scripts that check for that particular failure.

Comment: Thanks for helping out, I'll go create some more diagrams and look for ways to break my system ;)

Comment: I use "what if the server gets restarted right now" scenario to detect some state inconsistencies, it it helps you

Comment: You mean that on startup of the application you check for inconsistencies?

Comment: Yes, or on cron/as scheduled task

Comment: Thanks, I'll see how this applies to my situation